# Error: Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment

Tags: error

We are using CiviCRM 4.6.9, and Drupal (where do I find version #??)

Suddenly a few days ago the following message began appearing:
[image: Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment. DB Error: unknown error]

The screenshot is from my dashboard; the message also appears when attempting to view or edit most contact records.  Most but not all, and I haven't found any pattern.

As far as I know, we have not recently updated Drupal or Civi.

Why are we suddenly getting this message?  What can I do?

More information: the problem has gone away all by itself, so I still don't know what really happened.  And that's OK by me for now.

Thanks for the helpful answers - I found the file with backtrace, and also found where to turn debugging & backtrace on and off for next time.  So a helpful learning experience.

Comment: enabling debugging will show you more information about the issue.

example.com/civicrm/admin/setting/debug?reset=1

Comment: Check your logs- sites/default/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog

Comment: shrish is correct - I recommend going to **Administer menu > System Settings > Debugging and Error Handling**, select "Yes" to both "Enable Debugging" and "Display Backtrace", and press "Save".  Repeat the problem that caused your error, and you'll see much a much more detailed error.  Please update this question with the expanded error and backtrace - and don't forget to disable debugging/backtrace when you're done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get more details in civicrm log file (*/file/civicrm/ConfigAndLog). Also the main reason of this type error is, we are using few fields that are disabled. check custom fields status that are using for contact.

Answer (score 1):

Had this issue and resolved it by disabling the *only_full_group_by* setting

```
mysql> set global sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
mysql> set session sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

Comment: For more on the `only_full_group_by` setting, see https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/requirements/#mysql-configuration